# Sidekiq queue name

Tags: ruby

In sidekiq you can specify the name of the queue you want to add that job into, so what's the benefit from separating jobs in multiple queues? why do we need to not put all jobs in the default queue?

Comment: so you can handle different priorities

Answer (score 0):

In my current project we send a lot of jobs to Sidekiq.  One type of job we submit about 200,000 jobs a day.  For another type (sending email to users) we send maybe 100.  If they were all in the same queue then there is a very good chance that "please confirm your account" email will be in the 200,001st spot and won't get run for a long time (hours?).  By having multiple queues I can ensure that those 100 get sent out promptly.